# I have a 12v 6ah Peltier Mini Fridge will using a 12v 10ah power supply harm the Peltier?

Tags: power, peltier

Hi all I have a commercially made mini fridge which displays it power requirements of 12v DC 6ah power supply. I have a 12v DC 10ah smp power supply. Can I use it with the Peltier fridge without harming anything or do I need to put resistor in line to limit the Ah output.

Comment: Thought experiment: I have a 6 W (0.5 A) lightbulb for my car. My car battery can supply 200 A. Can I use the bulb in my car?

Comment: Please check again. I bet you there is no h, only A on both the device and the power supply.

Comment: The fridge and power supply are most likely not rated in "Ah" to begin with. Also this should be closed as duplicate or product usage question.